# Using a stack and push and pop functions to convert BST into an array

Tags: c, string, stack, binary-tree

I am having an issue with the last part of my program. I am supposed to change a BST into an array using a stack. I get a segfault error when I try and do this part of the program. I am going to post a little bit of my code to give you guys an idea of what I want to do, then post the output that I am supposed to have using this function. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
typedef struct TreeNode_ {
    char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    struct TreeNode_ *left;
    struct TreeNode_ *right;
}TreeNode;


typedef struct StackNode_ {
    TreeNode *t;
    struct StackNode_ *next;
}StackNode;

char** flatten_tree(TreeNode* node, int *len_strings);
void push_node(StackNode** top, TreeNode* t);
TreeNode* pop_node(StackNode** top);
int size(TreeNode *node);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    /*
     * Check command line parameters
     * */
    if (argc < 2) {
            printf("%s is missing parameters to run properly\n", argv[0]);
            return 1;
    }
    TreeNode* root = NULL;
    root = read_from_file(argv[1]);
    char buffer[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    char buffer2[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    display_tree(root,START_DEPTH);

    printf("Trimming the database from %s to %s\n\n", buffer, buffer2);
    root = trim_tree(root,buffer,buffer2);

    display_tree(root,START_DEPTH);

    int size = 0;
    char** strings = flatten_tree(root,&size);
    int i = 0;
    printf("\nFlattened databse is:\n");


    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
            free(strings[i]);
    }
    free(strings);
}
}

int size(TreeNode* node) {

    if(node==NULL){
    return 0;
    }
    else{
            return(size(node->left) + 1 + size(node->right));
}}


char** flatten_tree(TreeNode* node, int *len_strings) {

    *len_strings = size(node);
    char *strings = malloc(sizeof(len_strings));
    TreeNode* current = node;
    StackNode* s = NULL;
    int done = 0;
    int i = 0;

    *strings = strings[i];


    while(!done){

            if(current != NULL){
                    push_node(&s, current);
                    current = current->left;
            }
            else{
                    if(s){
                            current = pop_node(&s);
                            current = current->right;
                            strings[i++];
                    }
                    else
                            done = 1;
}
}
}

void push_node(StackNode** top, TreeNode* t) {

    StackNode *newPtr = NULL;

    if(newPtr != NULL)
    {
            newPtr->t = t;
            newPtr->next = *top;
            *top = newPtr;
    }

}

TreeNode* pop_node(StackNode** top_ref) {

    StackNode *top = *top_ref;

    if(top){
            StackNode *temp = top->next;
            free(top_ref);
            *top_ref = top;
    }
}
```

The output of this program is supposed to look like this:

```
 -
        bob
            -
    erik
            -
        james
            -
matt
            -
        nick
                -
            sachin
                -
sue
    -


Flattened database is:
bob
erik
james
matt
nick
sachin
sue
```

My output is this:

```
-
        bob
            -
    erik
            -
        james
            -
matt
            -
        nick
                -
            sachin
                -
sue
    -


Flattened database is:
segmentation fault
```

Comment: Supposed to look like this... and what it actually looks like is... ? :)

Comment: Oh it displays the tree, but it seg faults at the flattened database part so that doesnt display. I left out a bunch of functions though that would display the bst

Comment: `flatten_tree` does not have a `return` statement

Comment: Don't tell me. Add it to your question ;) Would especially be good if you copied and pasted exactly what it looks like now so we can compare against what it should look like. You should know: nobody on this site wants to run your code just to figure out how to help you with it... so it's best to provide everything in your explanation.

Comment: `char *strings = malloc(sizeof(len_strings));` is a blunder on multiple levels.  `sizeof(len_strings)` is the size of a pointer (probably 4 or 8 bytes). `strings[i++];` has no effect on `strings`, `*strings = strings[i]` reads uninitialized values, and this is not suitable for having its address returned (if that was your intention)

Comment: How do I malloc the strings then?

Comment: Also, the `push_node` function never actually pushes a node.

Comment: You seem a bit out of your depth here , maybe do some simpler exercises before coming back to this task . Search SO for other posts on how to return a malloc'd array of strings.

Comment: Dang okay ill try, but this is due in a few hours and these are the last 2 functions I need, I will still get an A without these though luckily.

Comment: This question is remarkably similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24790986/converting-a-bst-into-an-array-using-a-stack, does "chicken liver" sit next to you in class?

Comment: `char **strings = malloc(*len_strings*sizeof(char *));`//strings use it as the return value

Answer (score 0):

`push_node` is using an uninitialized local variable (`newPtr`); if it does't happen to be `NULL`, using it would probably cause a seg-fault.

**Update**: Why not try declaring `strings` as `char strings[`*max-#-of-nodes*`][MAX_NAME_LEN]` globally, and get the code to fill & print it working?  Once that is done, you can go back and handle the dynamic allocation.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, I still am getting a seg fault though